# How to get the file contents using input file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

Using file upload i tried to get the json data.

File upload code :

```
<input
        accept=".json" 
        id="contained-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
        onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e.target.files) }
      />
      <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" component="span">
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
```

handle change function

```
handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList)
    {
           const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(selectorFiles[0]);
            fileReader.onload = (e) => { 
                var finResult =  e.target.result ;
                 
            };

}
```

but i am getting data:application/json;base64,blob in console. instead of getting the json output.

Comment: Try [`.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using readAsDataURL to read the file, which gives you a data URL (data:application/json etc)

Try using readAsText instead: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText%60)

```
handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList) {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(selectorFiles[0]);
  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    const contents = e.target.result;
    console.log(contents);
  };
}
```

You can also use the newer File.text() as well

```
selectorFiles[0].text().then(contents => {
  // do something with the contents of the file
});
```